# Camunda external Java task: "Cannot deserialize object in variable"

Tags: java, serialization, camunda

I am implementing a Java ExternalTaskHandler, to handle a Camunda External Task. I am returning an array of objects as a result of the task. Unfortunately when I return this array, I get an error, that Camunda is not able to deserialize my object.

My code is the following:

```
public class MyClass implements ExternalTaskHandler 
{
    public void execute(ExternalTask externalTask, ExternalTaskService externalTaskService) 
    {
        // Construct the returned object
        List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        myObjects.add(new MyObject());

        // Put it in the response
        Map<String,Object> returnedObjects = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        returnedObjects.put("myObjects", myObjects);

        // Finish the task -- this is where the error occurs
        externalTaskService.setVariables(externalTask, returnedObjects);
    }
}
```

The error is the following:

```
TASK/CLIENT-01009 Exception while completing the external task: 
The corresponding process instance could not be resumed. Reason: status code: 500, reason phrase: 
{"type":"ProcessEngineException","message":"Cannot deserialize object in variable 'returnedObjects': SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01007 Cannot construct java type from string 'java.util.ArrayList<my.test.MyObject>'","code":0}
```

Interestingly, if I replace the list of MyObject with a List of String, let's say, then the code works.

What should I add or configure to allow Camunda to deserialize my object successfully?

---

EDIT: here is the implementation of `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private String name;
    
    private List<String> values;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code of `my.test.MyObject`

Comment: @MichaelKatt It has a List<String> inside. That's it. With a getter and setter of course.

Comment: It is a question of serialization or of camunda knowing your class. Therefore I am asking for your implementation of `my.test.MyObject`. Is it flagged with the interface `Serializable`? Is the field not transient? Are you using custom serialiszation? And for Camunda: Do Camundo know your Class? Did you add a dependency of the your JAR with `my.test.MyObject` to your custom Camunda part?

Comment: @MichaelKatt Thank you for your response. I have edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making your object a Serializable may technically be the solution, you should not use Java serialization for process data.

In more recent Camunda 7 releases Java serialization has be deprecated. Reasons include the **language dependence and tight coupling** it creates. Different consumers of the process data need to have the Java class available. Every update to it requires updates to other services accessing the data. Versioning of Serializables is another challenge...

Anyway: You should **serialize to JSON**. This way any client (Java or not) will be able to work with the data, you can easily work with the data in a human readable format, can use different programming languages, can use jsonPath to navigate it in the process, have better interoperability with DMN/FEEL, can easily use it on the UI layer if needed,... and are better prepared - **in Camunda 8 JSON is the only supported serialization** and FEEL is the expression language (no more JUEL).

Here is an example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/c7-rest-task-worker/blob/bff52eccfe569dcd25f39231906f9e209c5b4467/src/main/java/com/camunda/example/worker/RESTWorker.java#L33

Also see: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/next/guides/migrating-from-camunda-platform-7/#use-primitive-variable-types-or-json

Answer (score 0):

The error message contains this hint

> Cannot deserialize object in variable

If you need to serialize/deserialize a class, this class has to implement the interface `java.io.Serializable`. And any class used for fields in that class have toimplement the interface `Serializable` also.

As shown in the question, your class `MyObject` does not implement the interface `Serializable`

```
public class MyObject {
```

Now looking at the fields of `MyObject`

```
private String name;
```

`String` implements `Serializable` therefore `String` ist serializable.

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {

private List<String> values;
```

As interface `List` and its inherited interfaces do not implement the interface `Serializable` it depends on the used implementation of `List` if it is serializable. `ArrayList` for example is serializable.

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E> {
public interface Iterable<T> {

public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

As conclusion you have to add the interface `Serializable`

public class MyObject implements Serializable

and you have to use a serializable implementation of `List`.

To learn more about serialization at [Oracle guide serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html)